# Multi-label classification where predicting any one label is fine

Tags: cross-entropy, multilabel

I am working on a problem with muti-label classification, where, in contrast to the conventional requirement that the correct prediction of each label is expected, we just need to predict ANY ONE of the labels. I.e., it usually has more than one correct answer, but you only need to choose one.

I am currently using the `softmax` and CE loss to distinguish **one** correct scores (the largest one) against **all** wrong scores. Is there any better use way to tackle this problem?